# How to blend two SDL2 textures to one texture?

Tags: textures, sdl, blend

```
SDL_RenderClear(g_ren);

SDL_Texture *tex_bk = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(g_ren, bk);

SDL_Texture *tex_des = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(g_ren, widget);
SDL_RenderCopy(g_ren, tex_bk, NULL, NULL);
SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(tex_des,blendMode);
SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(g_ren,blendMode);

SDL_RenderCopy(g_ren, tex_des, NULL, NULL);

SDL_RenderPresent(g_ren);
SDL_DestroyTexture(tex_des);
SDL_DestroyTexture(tex_bk);
```

I want use SDL_RenderCopy to copy the tex_bk and second time I use the SDL_RenderCopy blend the tex_des  .but the application always show the tex_des image.tex_bk image always disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the functions.

`SDL_SetTextureBlendMode` changes the way how the alpha blending is applied for a specified texture.

`SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode` changes the way how the alpha blending is done for rendering primitives, like points, lines and rectangles.

---

The function you are looking for is probably `SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod`.

Comment: Is there a good resource for reading more about what alphaMod does?